# JavaScript para verificar se o bloqueador de popup está ativo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup

Preciso fazer um JavaScript para uma aplicação que verifique se o bloqueador de popup está ativo. Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  var Janela = window.open('', '', '');
  if(Janela==null){
      alert('Não Abriu!!!');
  }
});
```

Porém, queria algo que não abrisse uma aba pra fazer essa verificação, pois a cada vez que acionar esse método, se tiver liberado o popup, vai abrir uma nova aba pro usuário.

Comment: Fui dar uma pesquisada para ver se é possível verificar sem, de fato, abrir uma popup, e não me pareceu muito plausível. Dá uma olhada aqui:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup

Comment: É, realmente... Eu também não estou encontrando nada que possibilite fazer a verificação sem abrir uma popup.  :(

Comment: Como até agora não consegui... Por hora, uma medida paliativa foi fazer:
    Janela.blur();
    Janela.close();

Answer (score 1):

Se você usa JavaScript para abrir o pop-up, pode usar algo como isto:

```
    var newWin = window.open(url);             

    if(!newWin || newWin.closed || typeof newWin.closed=='undefined') 
    { 
        //popup bloqueado
    }
```

[Essa questão já foi respondida no stackoverflow.com, veja aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup)